Timeout problem on SQL script in MariaDB: connection closed after 2 hours
I am experiencing a particular problem when running an SQL script on a database managed with MariaDB. When I run the script, the connection closes after exactly 2 hours, interrupting the execution of the query. I am certain that the query is correct, because when I run it on a smaller dataset, the results are returned without any problems.
I have ruled out the possibility that the problem could be related to the server or the firewall, as a colleague of mine executed the same query without interruption. This leads me to think that the problem is client-side.
I have tried running the query with both DBeaver and DataGrip, changing some generic timeout settings, but the problem persists. Has anyone had a similar problem or knows how to solve it?
Thanks in advance for any help!
[logs error]
[socket timeout]
I tried to solve the problem by changing various settings in both the client and the driver, but without success. Even after these changes, the socket goes into timeout when the query takes more than 2 hours to execute.

The error message is not very helpful not being in English.

Sorry, I hadn't noticed. This is the error log in English: "Unable to establish connection. Incorrect response from the connected party after the time interval or no response from the connected host"

Have you tried running the query by executing it directly from the MySQL CLI to narrow down the cause? If it's reproduced from the console, the issue is certainly not in the database connector app. However, if it's finished without timeouts, I'd urge you to post this issue on our tracker, including the idea log and database log
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE
